# calling sub interface method from parent interface

Tags: java, methods, interface, default, extends

How can I call interface i2 default method disp2() from interface i1 default method disp1().Is it possible?

```
interface i1 { 
    default void disp1() { System.out.println("Super interface"); }
}

interface i2 extends i1 {
    default void disp2() { System.out.println("Sub  interface"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By casting.

E.g. if you have a class that implements `i2`, and so `i1` as well:

```
public class C implements i2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        c.disp1();
    }
}
```

The `disp1()` method can cast itself to be an `i2` if safe:

```
interface i1 {
    default void disp1() {
        System.out.println("Super interface");
        if (this instanceof i2)
            ((i2) this).disp2();
    }
}
```

This will output both lines:

```
Super interface
Sub  interface
```

Or as a more object oriented approach, could you add the `disp2()` method to `i1`?  Then `i2` would simply override it:

```
interface i1 {
    default void disp1() {
        System.out.println("Super interface");
        ((i2) this).disp2();
    }

    default void disp2() {

    }
}
```